# Insert data in different server in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to insert data from one table in one server to another server using SQL languages in MySQL? We can do it in MS SQLServer by reference server name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I transfer data between 2 MySQL databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242504/how-can-i-transfer-data-between-2-mysql-databases)

Comment: i want to avoid dump file it make a lot of work as we have to schedule back up from server 1 and schedule insert in server 2  since it contain lot of hug data ( it over 110,000 records per day)

Comment: let me try , thank you .

Answer (score 0):

1. first you need the structure of your database with tables and other objects(views,data,indexes,etc).
2. create a backup of your database with all tables and objects of your database and save it on files .sql, por example a dump file.
3. if you need insert data in different servers, you can create the database in each of  your servers. You can execute this backup (a sql file with tables and other objects of database) in each server.
4. if your tables dont have data you can load data in mysql via load  data ([MYSQL import data from csv using LOAD DATA INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/mysql-import-data-from-csv-using-load-data-infile)) or through other way.

Comment: yeah it is in different server . let me try the forth option . thanks you .

Comment: see another answer :)