# Faster transfer of 2 billion records between two database tables

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection, prepared-statement

The script below fetches each row from table (`q_iTable`) having 2 billion records in database `db1`, gets two column values (`iIndex` and `pIndex`) and modifies them into json data structure. This modified data is then inserted into `iTable` in `db2`. Also, the values of columns from the two tables are checked and the update or insert of `iTable` in `db2` is done accordingly.

This transfer of data from `q_iTable` to `iTable` is currently being done at a rate of 700 records/minute which will basically takes years to transfer the entire 2 billion record. I would like to know how I can make this process quick such that the entire 2 billion record can be transferred faster. Any help/guidance would be highly appreciated!

```
public class Transfer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Transfer.class);
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stat = null;
        ResultSet results = null;
        Connection con2 =null;
        Statement stmt2 = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:ip_address/port", "username", "password");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            stat = con.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT * FROM db1.q_iTable;",
                    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            stat.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            results = stat.executeQuery();

            con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:ip_address/port", "username", "password");
            stmt2 = con2.createStatement();
            while (results.next()) {
                String iSerial = results.getString("iSerial");
                String iIndex = results.getString("iIndex");
                String pIndex = results.getString("pIndex");

                JSONObject jsonSubObject = null;
                JSONArray jsonArrayRET = new JSONArray();
                jsonSubObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonSubObject.put("iIndex", iIndex);
                jsonSubObject.put("pIndex", pIndex);

                jsonArrayRET.add(jsonSubObject);

                String properties = jsonArrayRET.toString();

                String prevSQL = "SELECT * FROM db2.iTable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
                ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery( prevSQL );
                if(rs.next()) {
                    String previSerial = rs.getString("iSerial");
                    String previIndex = rs.getString("iIndex");
                    String prevpIndex = rs.getString("pIndex");

                    if((previSerial.equals(iSerial)) && (previIndex.equals(iIndex))) {
                        String query = "update db2.iTable set iIndex=\""+iIndex+"\" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
                        stmt2.executeUpdate(query);
                    } else {
                        String query = "insert into db2.iTable values(" + NULL + ", \'" + iSerial + "\', \'" + properties + "\');";
                        stmt2.executeUpdate(query);
                    }
                } else  {
                    String query = "insert into db2.iTable values(" + NULL + ", \'" + iSerial + "\', \'" + properties + "\');";
                    stmt2.executeUpdate(query);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("cannot connect", e);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            results.close();
            stat.close();
            con.close();
            con2.close();
            stmt2.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT with incorporating addBatch() and executeBatch():**

I am using addBatch() and executeBatch() but I am not observing much of a difference with the data transfer rate. Any suggestions?

```
public class Transfer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Transfer.class);
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stat = null;
        ResultSet results = null;
        Connection con2 =null;
        Statement stmt2 = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:ip_address/port", "username", "password");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            stat = con.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT * FROM db1.q_iTable;",
                    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            stat.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            results = stat.executeQuery();

            con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:ip_address/port", "username", "password");
            stmt2 = con2.createStatement();
            while (results.next()) {
                int count = 0;
                String iSerial = results.getString("iSerial");
                String iIndex = results.getString("iIndex");
                String pIndex = results.getString("pIndex");

                JSONObject jsonSubObject = null;
                JSONArray jsonArrayRET = new JSONArray();
                jsonSubObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonSubObject.put("iIndex", iIndex);
                jsonSubObject.put("pIndex", pIndex);

                jsonArrayRET.add(jsonSubObject);

                String properties = jsonArrayRET.toString();

                String prevSQL = "SELECT * FROM db2.iTable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
                ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery( prevSQL );
                if(rs.next()) {
                    String previSerial = rs.getString("iSerial");
                    String previIndex = rs.getString("iIndex");
                    String prevpIndex = rs.getString("pIndex");

                    if((previSerial.equals(iSerial)) && (previIndex.equals(iIndex))) {
                        String query = "update db2.iTable set iIndex=\""+iIndex+"\" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
                        stmt2.addBatch(query);
                    } else {
                        String query = "insert into db2.iTable values(" + NULL + ", \'" + iSerial + "\', \'" + properties + "\');";
                        stmt2.addBatch(query);
                    }
                } else  {
                    String query = "insert into db2.iTable values(" + NULL + ", \'" + iSerial + "\', \'" + properties + "\');";
                    stmt2.addBatch(query);
                }
                if (count % 1000 == 0 ) {
                    pgStmt.executeBatch();
                    pgCon.commit();
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("cannot connect", e);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            results.close();
            stat.close();
            con.close();
            con2.close();
            stmt2.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355097/4933735 . Also see comments of this answer.

Comment: ... and also that question's [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23938071/2144390) which talks about `rewriteBatchedStatements=true`

Comment: @A.Görünücü, I tried using batch but haven't observed a big difference yet. I have added the modified code in the EDIT section above. Thanks

Comment: Your code suggests that db2.iTable may be empty when the process starts. Will that always be the case?

Comment: You are reading `q_iTable` row-by-row which will always be the slowest way to process the data. If possible, I'd suggest you leave out JDBC/Java and process the data with [native bulk operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242504/how-can-i-transfer-data-between-2-mysql-databases), handling JSON processing with [built-in functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html) while loading the data into the target DB. This will likely be orders of magnitude faster than what you'll achieve through JDBC.

Comment: @GordThompson, yes that would always be the case

Comment: @MickMnemonicI looked into it however, having for loop and if conditions would be challenging