# Transfer specific table data between Schemas with different passwords on Mysql

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I would like to select some data from a table in a schema and transfer from "SchemaExample1" to "SchemaExample2". These schemas have the same tables structures but they have different passwords.

For this, is the best approach to use this one?
[How can I transfer data between 2 MySQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242504/how-can-i-transfer-data-between-2-mysql-databases)

I also tried to use:

```
alter table SchemaExample1.testTable rename SchemaExample2.testTable2
```

but this one gives me the error:

```
INSERT,CREATE command denied to user 'SchemaExample1'@'localhost' for table 'test_testTable2'
```

Side notes:
I need to select part of the table on SchemaExample1.testTable and not the whole table.

I have two schemas, each one with their unique password:

- "SchemaExample1 and
- SchemaExample2;

to use these schemas I usually do like this:
 - mysql -u SchemaExample1 --password=test1;
 - mysql -u SchemaExample2 --password=test2;

Answer (score 0):

You can `mysqldump` one table and pipe that to `mysql -u SchemaExample2 --password=test2 Schema2` if you want the entire table copied as is.